# HTTP Status code for invalid resource specified in payload

Tags: rest, http, jersey, http-status-code-404, http-status-codes

I have a REST request (Not completely REST though). The input data is received via HTTP payload as XML and thus the record to be read is specified in the xml as,

`<Item>
  <ID>1</ID>
</Item>`

Here, if the `ID` '1' is not found in database, should I return 404 Not found.

According to https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html, `404 Not Found` is referred as `The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI.` But in my case, the URI can be reached successfully and the data in payload could not be found. Is it appropriate to use `404` or should I use any other status code?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, why are you sending a payload to retrieve data? If you want to retrieve data in a RESTful way, you should send the id in the path, like `/some-resource/1`. I hope there is a very good reason to don't follow that standard.

In any case, returning a `404` is the best approach, in my opinion. Any client would expect a `404` if the resource was not found, even when the formal definition specifies that the resource is in the URL.

Comment: yes, regardless of how you ask the server for the resource (url, xml payload) the result is the same, it's not there, 404